# How to send email with phone device information without user concern?

Tags: android, email, telephonymanager

I'm working on an security application in which my application will send a mail to the server automatically without the phone user disturbance. What I need is

1. **Colletct user phone number and imei number**
2. **Send a email with the information, but user don't know about the process.**
3. **When a user insert a new sim again a new email will be send with the above mentioned process**

**What I done till is :**

1. **Colletct user phone number and imei number using telephony manager**
2. **Save the information locally**

But I need an instruction or tutorial for doing rest of my work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in Version below M but above M you need to ask permission from the user so i suggest you to make a database and send data to server using background async task.

Here is tutorial to send email without intent http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent

Comment: It'll be a default app with phone, Installed by the phone provider before user get it.So that I can handle this issue I think. So how to send mail with those info s?  any tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: for the db issue primarily I thought about firebase. you can give me suggestion also.